# How to determine set of connected line from an array in python

Tags: python, numpy, nearest-neighbor

I have an array that looks something like:

[0  x1  0   0   y1   0   z1 
 0  0   x2  0   y2  0   z2  
 0  0   x3  0   0   y3  z3  
 0  0   x4  0   0   y4  z4 
 0  x5  0   0   0   y5  z5  
 0  0   0   0   y6   0   0]

I need to determine set of connected line (i.e. line that connects to the points [x1,x2,x3..], [y1,y2,y3...], [z1,z2,z3..]) from the array and then need to find maximum value in each line i.e. max{x1,x2,x3,...}, max{y1,y2,y3..} etc.  i was trying to do nearest neighbor search using kdtree but it return the same array. I have array of the size (200 x 8000). is there any easier way to do this? Thx.

Comment: I don't think this question is particularly clear. Do you have a list of zeros and strings such as 'x0' or are they 1s? What do you mean by the line? What are the rules of your line finding algorithm? Can they move diagonally?

Comment: @pelson 'x1','x2','x3', 'y1','y2' ... are all different values. i wrote 'x1' and 'y1' to differentiate that those values falls within different lines. I add a link to the figure to make it clear. I draw figure from the array which contains zeros and values as shown in original post. I need to find maximum values along each lines (the values in each lines are not in descending order). I couldn't upload figure here so i attached a link to the figure: i.imgur.com/W9O0I.png

Comment: In the example array you provided, how would you tell that the z3 doesn't exist on the y line? Is it that you want some kind of priority over descending (in terms of rows) numbers rather than those that move diagonally? Can lines move horizontally?

Comment: Points are mostly in vertical lines i.e. in similar column and they might shift one column to the left or to the right if point below that line is zero. z1,z2.. z5 are all in one column. In case of X line moves to the right at x2 and then it continue in that column until x4 and then shift to right at x5. I can do search on each point and i can trace all lines with if/else loop but it takes lots of resources as need to do it for 1600000 points. It might be easier if some methods are available trace those lines from image/array instead of doing it manually for all the points.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything which provides the functionality you desire out of the box. If you have already written the logic, and it is just slow, have you considered Cython-ing your code. For simple typed looping operations you could get a significant speedup.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of speeding up your line searching algorithm would be to pre-calculate the start points of each line, and then apply the expensive logic to calculate lines from each of these points.

I have taken a limited view of the logic (because you haven't provided the full line identification logic), which can compute the start points in fast vectorised code.

The first step in being able to implement such a thing in fast vectorised code is to be able to figure out which points are in a line, but their direct points above are not:

```
import numpy

# using the array that was provided in the question
a = """0 x1 0 0 y1 0 z1 
0 0 x2 0 y2 0 z2 
0 0 x3 0 0 y3 z3 
0 0 x4 0 0 y4 z4 
0 x5 0 0 0 y5 z5 
0 0 0 0 y6 0 0"""

array = numpy.array([int(v.strip()) if v.strip().isdigit() else i for i, v in enumerate(a.split(' '))]).reshape(6, 7)
```

Results in an array which looks like:

```
>>> print repr(array)
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  0,  4,  0,  6],
       [ 0,  0   9,  0, 11,  0, 13],
       [ 0,  0, 16,  0,  0, 19, 20],
       [ 0,  0, 23,  0,  0, 26, 27],
       [ 0, 29,  0,  0,  0, 33, 34],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 39,  0,  0]])
```

From here, we can do some numpy rolling:

```
 >>> print `numpy.roll(array, 1, axis=0)`
 array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0, 39,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  4,  0,  6],
        [ 0,  0,  9,  0, 11,  0, 13],
        [ 0,  0, 16,  0,  0, 19, 20],
        [ 0,  0, 23,  0,  0, 26, 27],
        [ 0, 29,  0,  0,  0, 33, 34]])
```

Which can be combined to give us the vertical start points of the lines:

```
>>> potential_start_points = (array != 0) & (numpy.roll(array, 1, axis=0) == 0)
>>> # include the top row points, as they are certainly start points
>>> potential_start_points[0, :] = (array != 0)[0, :]
>>> print `potential_start_points`
array([[False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

From here, it is possible to refine the vectorised logic to pick out diagonals etc., but I would be tempted to iterate over each of the Trues and apply more complex index based logic.

```
xs, ys = numpy.where(potential_start_points)

for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    # do more complex logic here ...
```

After all, the problem, in this case, is now reduced from iterating over 6x7=42 numbers to iterating over just 7.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try the way you suggested.